# how to search word from String field in Lucene Index

Tags: lucene, indexing

## How to search word from Lucene index String field ?

i have lucene index with field **TITLE** ,containts Document titles

eg:**TV not working,Mobile not working**

i want to search particular word from title .

code below gives me result from Full content,if i change FULL_CONTENET to TITLE then i dont get any results.

```
Query qry = null;
qry = new QueryParser(FULL_CONTENT, new SimpleAnalyzer()).parse("not");
Searcher searcher = null;
searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);
Hits hits = null;
hits = searcher.search(qry);
System.out.println(hits.length());
```

Comment: How did you index your documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "NOT" is a Lucene query syntax operator, that may be your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `StringAnalyzer` applies a Lower Case filter. Your query will be in lower case:

e.g. title:mobile.

`StringField` doesn't apply any analysis so your text will be indexed as is. If you change `StringField` to `TextField` it will be analyzed by the `StringAnalyzer` and get converted to lower case in the index.

If you replace `StringAnalyzer` with `WhitespaceAnalyzer` there is no Lower Case filter and it will work again (because your query doesn't get converted to lower case).